# finding probablities given a function

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Let

$$ F(x) = \frac{1}{4} \chi_{[0, \infty)}(x) + \frac{1}{2} \chi_{[1, \infty)}(x) + \frac{1}{4}\chi_{[2, \infty) } (x) $$

Suppose the probablity $P$ is given by $P( ( -\infty, x]) = F(x) $. IF, say $A = ( -\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} ) , B = [0,2) $, $C = (3, \infty)$ , I want to find $P(A),P(B),P(C)$

My idea to solve the problem is obviously to express the sets $A,B,C$ in unions, or intersections of intervals of the form $(- \infty, x ] $. For instance $(3 , \infty) = ( - \infty, 3]^c $. Hence,

$$ P( ( 3 , \infty) ) = 1 - P( (- \infty, 3] ) = 1  - F(3) 1 - 1/4 - 1/2 - 1/4 = \frac{1}{2}$$

IS this correct approach? Also, I cant seem to express the sets $A$ and $B$ in sets of the the given form. IS there a shortcut to do this problem? thanks

Comment: It should be $P((3,\infty))=0$. The approach seems to be correct by the way. But an easier way would be just to observe that the distribution has three discrete masses at $0,1,2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach is correct. But, as mentioned in the comment, it would be easier to observe that the distribution has three discrete masses at $0,1,2$. Then, $P(A)=P(X=0)=1/4;\ P(B)=1/4+1/2=3/4;\ P(C)=0$ as the random variable $X$ does not take any value in the set $C$.

Comment: thanks for your response!. I was practicing with other events and I got this: $P( ( - \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2} ) ) = 1 $, and $P( \frac{2}{3}, \frac{5}{2} ) ) = \frac{3}{4} $. Are they correct?

Comment: The first one is incorrect. It should be $P((-1/2,3/2))=P(X=0)+P(X=1)=3/4;\ P((2/3,5/2))=P(X=1)+P(X=2)=3/4$. Maybe I can tell where you went wrong if you show how you got these.